# Hi, I have problems with my media queries in production, while it works on localhost. (React, css, scss, styled components, heroku, Webpack)

Tags: css, reactjs, heroku, media-queries

The site I am building is working perfectly on my localhost. Tech stack: react, node, heroku, styled components, sass.I just finished my media queries. However, when I push to production on heroku, everything works perfectly fine, the css gets applied, all nice. Except the media queries. Anyone any experience with this? The only thing I can think of is that the minify process of the css file screws with with specific syntax of the media query (the spaces in this part: @media screen and (max-width: 800px)). If anyone has a clue, thank you in advance :)!

An example of my styled component. I think it's not the css itself as it is working on localhost.

```
export const PreviewContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    display: grid !important;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr !important;
    gap: 30px !important;
  }
`;
```

Thank you for checking it out, with kind regards,
Stijn

Comment: Did you check your devtool to see the css that is applied and the eventual syntax errors ?

Comment: Yes, it shows that all styles I have applied without media queries are applied properly. Is simply does not change anything if I resize it to  a width lower than 800. The site is live @ stias.nl . Where I tried to apply this is on the shop page. However, it's not working anywhere, e.g. the header should be different and the homepage as well.^^